# parse a string with no spaces with scanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

I got a string like this:

```
111222abcd12ae
```

I want to split it in 4 numerical variables and i would like to do it in a single code line with `sscanf`. 
That's what i tried so far:

```
sscanf(mystring, "%3d%3d%4x%4x", &v1, &v2, &v3, &v4)
```

as you can see

- v1 should store the decimal value of chars 0 to 2
- v2 should store the decimal value of chars 3 to 5
- v3 should store the hexa value of chars 6 to 9
- v4 should store the hexa value of chars 10 to 13

Actual result: only `v4` is set.

How can i fix my format string in order to get what i want?

**UPDATE**

I found the problem... i've declared my variables as `unsigned short` instead of `int` (for `%d`) and `unsigned int` (for `%x`) and i got an unexpected result.

Comment: `printf("%3d %3d %4x %4x", v1, v2, v3, v4);` I get `111 222 abcd 12ae`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine for me, just as you wrote it.

Here's a complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *mystring = "111222abcd12ae";
    int v1, v2;
    unsigned int v3, v4;
    const int ret = sscanf(mystring, "%3d%3d%4x%4x", &v1, &v2, &v3, &v4);
    printf("conversion returned %d\n", ret);
    if(ret == 4)
    {
        printf("v1=%d\nv2=%d\nv3=%x\nv4=%x\n", v1, v2, v3, v4);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running it, I get:

```
conversion returned 4
v1=111
v2=222
v3=abcd
v4=12ae
```

Are you running this on some embedded platform or something, so that errors/limitations in `sscanf()` can be suspected?

Comment: Damn! I feel so stupid... i declared unsigned short instead of unsigned int my v variables and i got an unexpected result!

Comment: Ah, that's annoying. You should be able to get compiler warnings for that kind of conversion/variable mismatch. Also, remember that `%x` expects `unsigned int`. while `%d` takes `int`.